# Removing apostrophes and non numeric characters from 3d coordinates - python

Tags: python

I am trying to read in a txt file that contains 3D coordinates, in x y and z arrays. However, when printing the results the string contains apostrophes and other non numeric characters '()' that i do not want - as i will be using the data to make plots. How can i remove these? As a side note i would also like to take the first row and have it as a new matrix x1,y1,z1. I have already tried converting the string to a float, removing the brackets from the actual text file, using is.digit (which returns false as there are non numeric characters, the () which contain the source position) and other methods posted here to no avail. New to python/programming - thanks for the help.

code:

```
x=[]
y=[]
z=[]

data = np.genfromtxt('data0.txt', delimiter=',', dtype=float)
for row in myFile:
  x.append(row[0])
  y.append(row[1])
  z.append(row[2])

print(x)
print(y)
print(z)`
```

results:

```
['(-0.3', '-1.1', '-1.7', '-0.74', '-0.14', '-0.23', '-12.0', '-1.8', 
'-1.17', '-17.0', '0.43', '-0.58', '-1.58', '9.8', '-0.76', '-0.98', 
'-1.1']
[' -1.1', '-2.45', '-4.4', '-1.77', '-0.34', '-0.57', '-28.0', '-4.5', 
'-2.63', '-47.0', '0.65', '-1.58', '-3.79', '23.35', '-1.5', '-2.49', 
'-2.8']
[' 1.36)', '2.7', '5.5', '2.4', '0.24', '0.54', '32.0', '6.9', '3.25', 
'58.0', '-1.0', '1.94', '4.6', '-28.29', '1.35', '3.7', '3.26']
```

desired results: x, y, z values printed in matrices without apostrophes and without '()' brackets.

This is the source file (which is uploaded on my jupyter hub):

```
-0.3, -1.1, 1.36
-1.1,-2.45,2.7
-1.7,-4.4,5.5
-0.74,-1.77,2.4
-0.14,-0.34,0.24
-0.23,-0.57,0.54
-12.0,-28.0,32.0
-1.8,-4.5,6.9
-1.17,-2.63,3.25
-17.0,-47.0,58.0
0.43,0.65,-1.0
-0.58,-1.58,1.94
-1.58,-3.79,4.6
9.8,23.35,-28.29
-0.76,-1.5,1.35
-0.98,-2.49,3.7
-1.1,-2.8,3.26
```

Comment: You'd be better including your best attempt. As it stands, this is quite unclear

Comment: Can you edit the question with an example of the problematic strings?

Comment: If I understand correctly, it seems like you are based on the IDE's output console to gather your results? Why don't you try to write the data to a new txt file and use that instead? If you provide some code we can introduce some extensions to help you out!

Comment: Just looking in the picture, it seems like `dtype=str` parses strings instead of actual float numbers. In order to parse floats from your data file use `dtype=float`

Comment: @GregK. I have tried to change dtype=float and still obtain the same results. I have included an edit which shows my txt file.

Comment: @usr2564301 Perhaps I did explain it well I meant just what you said

Comment: @MathewMcPhillips I apologize if I did not explain it well, what I meant was for you to copy the text of the code in the image along with the input and output in a way it could be copied in a text editor

Comment: @DanielMesejo Thankyou I am also new to stackoverflow. I have edited my post including the code and results. Hope this makes it more clear.

Comment: @MatthewMcPhillips It will be great if you could add the first few lines of data0.txt

Comment: @DanielMesejo I have included an edit showing the txt file i am importing data from - just straight copied and pasted. Thankyou.

Comment: `'(-0.3'` and `[' 1.36)'` comes neither of your given source and program. I guess your real source contains `()`, which trouble `genfromtext` which infer string instead of float. Can you check your real source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original program works when I change it to

```
import numpy as np
x=[]
y=[]
z=[]

data0 = np.genfromtxt('data0.txt', delimiter=',', dtype=float, usecols=np.arange(0,3))
for row in data0:
    x.append(row[0])
    y.append(row[1])
    z.append(row[2])

    print(x)
    print(y)
    print(z)
```

So there's some inconsistency in a) the data file we've been given in the attached image and b) the program (where's myFile defined?)

I created a sample `data0.txt` file:

```
-0.3,-1.1,1.36
-1.1,-2.45,2.7
-1.7,-4.4,5,5
0,0,0
```

**Note:** I've removed all leading whitespace, so everything that's a number looks like a number.

I got these results

```
[-0.29999999999999999, -1.1000000000000001, -1.7, 0.0]
[-1.1000000000000001, -2.4500000000000002, -4.4000000000000004, 0.0]
[1.3600000000000001, 2.7000000000000002, 5.0, 0.0]
```

Comment: I think you are right that the data file given must be corrupted somehow. I copied and pasted the numbers to a new text file and obtained the same results as you. Success with eliminating apostrophes!!!  However, I need the program to output the exact numbers from the text file (e.g. -0.3 instead of -0.29999..)  as this data will be used for analysis of a very sensitive system. How would I fix this?

Comment: Those rounding problems are caused by converting binary floating point numbers to decimal floating point numbers and that's been a problem with computers for sixty years and more.  You'll need to apply a round() function to your data before you append it to your array.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over each list, filtering out braces and converting each item to a float, so:

```
float(a.replace('(','').replace(')',''))
```

for each item **a** in a list.